# AJAX Submission causing Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Trying to only submit a form when it's valid according to validator.min.js

I've tried to keep things as simple as possible

[**EDIT**] - This is updated as I've changed a few simple errors I noticed upon posting.

```
        $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#datafixForm').validator();
        e.preventDefault();


        var myForm = document.querySelector('#datafixForm');
        var formData = new FormData(myForm);

        var formIsValid = $('.form-group.has-error').length===0;


        if (formIsValid) {
            // Submit the form
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Form submitted!');
                    console.log('Recieved' + data);
                    alert('Form submitted!');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('We failed');
                    console.log('Got' + data);
                    alert('Didnt worky!');
                }
            });
            alert("Request Raised!");
        } else {
            alert("Form is invalid");
        }
    });
```

And the html:

```
    <form method="post" role="form" id="datafixForm" name="datafixForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Ref : <div class="text-danger">*required</div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group has-feedback">
            <input class="form-control" name="Id" id="Id" placeholder="Txxx" required pattern="^C[0-9][0-9]" data-error="Please choose a valid  ID" />
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary-outline center-block" >Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The validation of the content works, with the Form is Invalid alert firing when the required fields aren't filled in, however when it is valid I get an error in the console showing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

which appears to relate to the $.ajax({ call

Comment: Have you tried debugging to make sure that your form element collection is checking all of your form elements?

Comment: Not going to fix the problem, but there is no need to loop over all the elements to look for invalid, just do a selector. `var formIsValid  = $('.form-control.has-error').length===0;`

Comment: Now when is the error class being added to the form element? When the submit button is clicked or onchange of the input? If it is click of the submit button, I am guessing you are calling your function before the validate function has run.

Comment: @epascarello it's on change of the elements. each letter infact.

Comment: AHH, the error is on the div? Is it the div after it, the row, or the parent div?  You are looking at the input...

Comment: @epascarello yup - realised this problem moments after posting. Need to update the question now as something else doesn't work ;)